# VM Aborting Error - Android

Tags: android

Hi I am creating native API application in Android. This is running fine in AVD2.2, AVD3.1, AVD3.2, AVD4.0 and AVD4.0.3, but in **ADV2.3.3** i got an error as below

```
03-21 14:43:57.449: W/dalvikvm(527): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x4054ded8
points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;) 03-21 14:43:57.449:
I/dalvikvm(527): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE 03-21
14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0
obj=0x4051d360 self=0x1e6f38 03-21 14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   |
sysTid=536 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1994864 03-21
14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   | schedstat=( 1002040390 1270282115
139 ) 03-21 14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method) 03-21
14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method) 03-21
14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53) 03-21
14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
03-21 14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-21
14:43:57.449: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 03-21 14:43:57.459:
I/dalvikvm(527):   at
android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
03-21 14:43:57.459: I/dalvikvm(527):   at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 03-21 14:43:57.459:
E/dalvikvm(527): VM aborting
```

My Code is

```
final class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
            {   
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run()
                        {
                            jscmdprocessor.GetJSCommand(scriptname, args);
                        }
                    });
            }
    }
```

What i did wrong? Please help me.(I could not share full code)

Comment: I'm also getting a VM Aborting after a JNI warning... See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309521/weird-fatal-crash-with-exifinterface-and-vm-aborting

Comment: i think the fault is not in your code.. it is the emulator fault.